# ADB over WiFi connection lost on usb attached

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, usb, adb

**Context**

I'm working on an application that involves a hardware connected through a USB cable. In order to be able to debug my application, I need to do it over wifi, since the USB port is being used for communication with the hardware.

**Expected behavior**

Connect to device through ADB > Run the app > Connect the hardware > Select my app from App Chooser dialog > "new instance" of my app opens > Observe my logs printed to the logcat

**Current behavior**

Connect to device through ADB > Run the app > Connect the hardware > Select my app from App Chooser dialog > "new instance" of my app opens > ADB connection is lost

OBS: I'm not sure if I'm using the right nomenclature, correct me if I'm wrong. When I say "ADB connection is lost", I mean that the logcat stop printing anything, from my app or the system, but the actual WiFi connection between the ADB and the device is held (I don't need to `adb connect ip_address` again).

**Environment**

- Android 9
- Android Studio 4.1
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Hardware: DJI Phantom 4 Pro Remote Controller

Answer (score 1):

If all you're after is your logcat output and your app still actually runs on the device just use adb logcat.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Use the command and filter the logs of your application on the device.

If the device doesn't print anything from the logcat and the device doesn't output any errors in the logs then the device has to be crashing.

Comment: I consider this a workaround, since it doesn't actually fix the problem (connection lost), but allow me to see the logs